# Are there any restriction preventing you from using Demon to build Manse?

Tags: exalted-3e

One of my players wants to use a Demon he intends to summon to build him a Manse.

Looking at the rules this seems to be within the scope of a demon contract. Core Rule Book p.473

> Alternatively, she may assign it to complete a specific task—“Construct a tower using these plans,” “Murder Magistrate Yang,” “Dig a tunnel through this wall”—for as long as it takes to complete. Task-bound demons form a Defining Principle of “I must complete my task,” which is similarly impervious to tampering.

The core of the question I have is how can this be handled? But that question could be broken into a few subparts. Are there any rules that would apply to this situation, and what are they? Also looking for practical experience of how this has been handled by others, and how to avoid the player being able to build castle after castle just using demons as "free" labour. Prefer the suggestions of how to handle it to be linked to rules for 3rd edition.

It would be a bonus if the answer would adress if this would be different if the player "only" wanted to build a mundane tower.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Sure, you can. It might take a while, though, and the results might not be quite what you intended.

Building a Manse is either a Superior or Legendary crafting project, similar to crafting an artifact with an equivalent rating, but with the Craft (Geomancy) skill rather than the Craft (Artifacts) skill. That will require a pile of Craft XP, materials, and time. Additionally, many demons may lack the skills required to craft a working manse, or any sort of magical crafting whatsoever, and some might simply cheat by having powers that allow them to instantly conjure one (e.g. neomah being able to summon their bronze towers, or that one Third Circle demon who's a living manse and has the power to conjure new manses whenever she is summoned).

Given that these are demons we're talking about, it might have unsettling results or complications depending on what demon you've summoned; demons aren't looking for loopholes in your wording to screw you over, but they're also alien beings who might not value the same things you do. If you summon a bunch of firmin to build you a manse, they'll probably make it out of their resin spikes and impaled wildlife. If you summon hopping puppeteers to build you a manse, they'll happily shift all the rocks in accordance with your directions, but they're covered in narcotic mucus so you need to make sure nobody tries licking them or harvesting it. If you summon Alveua, she might start dragging nearby villagers off to forge them into shadowsteel for building the manse.

Of course, if your character is the one in charge of the project, and the demons are just summoned workers, then your character would be the one making the Craft rolls, and you'd maybe just get a non-charm bonus die for having high-quality "tools".

Comment: In the previous edition, summoned demons worked for Manse construction but were considered incredibly slow - even if your average First Circle Demon was worth 10 men, the limited rate of summoning one per day per Sorcerer meant it was much faster to just hire people.  However, you could get a decent boost by summoning three Second Circle Demons each month.  Using only summoned labor would take years without multiple Sorcerers or a specialized "labor summoning" spell, and to keep them around that long, you have to specify that project as a specific task, so they vanish when you finish.